# Very, *very* strange characters on Mac OS X after copy-paste from PDF

Tags: macos, special-characters, textedit

I did a copy-paste from a PDF, the text that should have been pasted is:

> (\<(/?[^\>]+)\>)

But, instead, I get some ***VERY*** strange characters. Demonstrated in the following screenshot:

[image: Weird 2]

The screenshot was taken from TextEdit, zoomed in a *lot*.

Does anyone have any idea as to what they are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are characters from the private use part of Unicode.

hence the "space alien"

Comment: Which means that the PDF encoding is off, yes?

Comment: Or the PDF is using a font that defines these somehow, and copy-pasting into a standard font is causing the issue.